# Release/production configuration for OpenSSL

Tags: configuration, openssl, centos7

I have a project that targets CentOS 7. I want to use an updated OpenSSL version for it. I am compiling from source the latest version, 3.2.1. To build, first we have to configure through the Configure script.

What is the recommended release/production build configuration? I want to obviously maximize first for security and the for speed.

So far, I have been using this config:
`./Configure no-weak-ssl-ciphers no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp -DOPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS -s -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -flto`